# Lua gsub case and frontier pattern

Tags: string, lua, gsub, scintilla, lua-patterns

Using Lua 5.1 and the gsub function how do I implement case sensitive/case insensitive and the frontier pattern matching option to count substrings?

```
 CountSubString = function(s,CtrlID)              --< s = string to count
  local t = Scintilla.GetText(CtrlID)
  if FindReplace.FindCase == 0 then               --< no case
   if FindReplace.FindWhole == 0 then             --< no whole word
    local _,count = string.gsub(t,s," ")
    return "Found "..count .." occourances of "..s 
   else                                           --< whole word
    local _,count = string.gsub(t,s," ")
    return "Found "..count .." occourances of "..s   
   end
  else                                            --< case
   if FindReplace.FindWhole == 0 then             --< no whole word
    local _,count = string.gsub(t,s," ")
    return "Found "..count .." occourances of "..s 
   else                                           --< whole word
    local _,count = string.gsub(t,s," ")
    return "Found "..count .." occourances of "..s   
   end 
  end
 end;
```

I've got an older post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156327/lua-frontier-pattern-match-whole-word-search) with the frontier pattern but it's having it case/non case also.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with this code?

Comment: there is no patterns in the gsub

Comment: Your linked question solves the case-sensitive part of this question (in both the whole word and sub-string cases) doesn't it? I'd include that in your post because, presumably, it is the case-insensitive bits that you are trying to work out now.

Comment: yes but I'm at a loss how to combine the frontier with the case part when the case part is known.