# Trying to check if a string contains a given word

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

```
function msgcontains(msg, what)
    msg = msg:lower()

    -- Should be replaced by a more complete parser
    if type(what) == "string" and string.find(what, "|", 1, true) ~= nil then
        what = what:explode("|")
    end

    -- Check recursively if what is a table
    if type(what) == "table" then
        for _, v in ipairs(what) do
            if msgcontains(msg, v) then
                return true
            end
        end
        return false
    end

    what = string.gsub(what, "[%%%^%$%(%)%.%[%]%*%+%-%?]", function(s) return "%" .. s end)
    return string.match(msg, what) ~= nil
end
```

This function is used on a RPG server, basically I'm trying to match what the player says

e.g; *if msgcontains(msg, "hi") then*

msg = the message the player sent

However, it's matching anything like "yesimstupid**hi**", it really shouldn't match it because "hi" isn't a single word, any ideas what can I do? T_T

Comment: Try `return string.match(' '..msg..' ', '%W'..what..'%W') ~= nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick mentioned by Egor in his comment, namely: add some non-word characters to the input string, and then enclose the regex with non-letter `%A` (or non-alphanumeric with `%W` if you want to disallow digits, too).

So, use

```
return string.match(' '..msg..' ', '%A'..what..'%A') ~= nil
```

or

```
return string.match(' '..msg..' ', '%W'..what..'%W') ~= nil
```

This code:

```
--This will print "yes im stupid hi" since "yes" is a whole word
msg = "yes im stupid hi"
if msgcontains(msg, "yes") then
    print(msg)
end
--This will not print anything
msg = "yesim stupid hi"
if msgcontains(msg, "yes") then
    print(msg)
end
```

Here is a [CodingGround demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMNncxbjktLThoZ1U)

Answer (score 4):

Frontiers are good for dealing with boundaries of the pattern (see   [Lua frontier pattern match (whole word search)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12156327/lua-frontier-pattern-match-whole-word-search)) and you won't have to modify the string:

```
return msg:match('%f[%a]'..what..'%f[%A]') ~= nil
```

The frontier `'%f[%a]'` matches only if the previous character was not in '%a' and the next is. The frontier pattern is available since 5.1 and official since 5.2.

Comment: Indeed! `%f` is available in 5.1.5!

Answer (score 0):

Just think about "what's a word". A word has specific characters in front and behind it, like whitespaces (space, tabulator, newline, carriage return, ...) or punctation (comma, semicolon, dot, line, ...). Furthermore a word can be at the text begin or end.

**%s**, **%p**, **^** and **$** should interest you.

For more, see [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1).